# Bar polar with areas proportional to values

Tags: python, plotly, bar-chart, polar-coordinates, plotly-express

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75126470/barplot-based-on-coloured-sectors/75128286#75128286) I have the plot below.
The issue is plotly misaligns the proportion between plot area and data value. I mean, higher values (e.g. going from 0.5 to 0.6) lead to a large increase in area (big dark green block) whereas from 0 to 0.1 is not noticiable (even if the actual data increment is the same 0.1).

[image: Plot]

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.wind()
df_test = df[df["strength"]=='0-1']

df_test_sectors = pd.DataFrame(columns=df_test.columns)

## this only works if each group has one row
for direction, df_direction in df_test.groupby('direction'):
    frequency_stop = df_direction['frequency'].tolist()[0]
    frequencies = np.arange(0.1, frequency_stop+0.1, 0.1)
    df_sector = pd.DataFrame({
        'direction': [direction]*len(frequencies),
        'strength': ['0-1']*len(frequencies),
        'frequency': frequencies
    })
    df_test_sectors = pd.concat([df_test_sectors, df_sector])
df_test_sectors = df_test_sectors.reset_index(drop=True)
df_test_sectors['direction'] = pd.Categorical(
    df_test_sectors['direction'], 
    df_test.direction.tolist() #sort the directions into the same order as those in df_test
)
df_test_sectors['frequency'] = df_test_sectors['frequency'].astype(float)
df_test_sectors = df_test_sectors.sort_values(['direction', 'frequency'])

fig = px.bar_polar(df_test_sectors, r='frequency', theta='direction', color='frequency', color_continuous_scale='YlGn')

fig.show()
```

Is there any way to make the plot with proportional areas to blocks to keep a more "truthful" alignment between the aesthetics and the actual data? So the closer to the center, the "longer" the blocks so the areas of all blocks are equal? Is there any option in Plotly for this?

Comment: currently we are using `frequency` as the `r` for sectors in the bar polar plot, but it sounds like we would need to create a new frequency feature adjusted so that the areas of the sectors stay the same (since they all have the same value, you want all of the areas to be the same) – am i correct in understanding the desired result?

Comment: @DerekO That's a good idea, creating a second variable just used for setting the sectors "radial axis length"  while letting the frequency as the true value shown in the color scale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can construct a new column called `r_outer_diff` that stores radius differences (as you go from the inner most to outer most sector for each direction) to ensure the area of each sector is equal. The values for this column can be calculated inside the loop we are using to construct `df_test_sectors` using the following steps:

- we start with the inner sector of `r = 0.1` and find the area of that sector as a reference since we want all subsequent sectors to have the same area
- then to construct the next sector, we need to find `r_outer` so that `pi*(r_outer-r_inner)**2 * (sector angle/360) = reference sector area`
- we solve this formula for r_outer for each iteration of the loop, and use r_outer as r_inner for the next iteration of the loop. since plotly will draw the sum of all of the radiuses, we actually want to keep track of `r_outer-r_inner` for each iteration of the loop and this is the value we will store in the `r_outer_diffs` column

Putting this into code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.wind()
df_test = df[df["strength"]=='0-1']

df_test_sectors = pd.DataFrame(columns=df_test.columns)

## this only works if each group has one row
for direction, df_direction in df_test.groupby('direction'):
    frequency_stop = df_direction['frequency'].tolist()[0]
    frequencies = np.arange(0.1, frequency_stop+0.1, 0.1)

    r_base = 0.1
    sector_area = np.pi * r_base**2 * (16/360) 

    ## we can populate the list with the first radius of 0.1
    ## since that will stay fixed
    ## then we use the formula: sector_area = pi*(r_outer-r_inner)^2 * (sector angle/360)
    r_adjusted_for_area = [0.1]
    r_outer_diffs = [0.1]
    for i in range(len(frequencies)-1):
        r_inner = r_adjusted_for_area[-1]
        inner_sector_area = np.pi * r_inner**2 * (16/360)
        outer_sector_area = inner_sector_area + sector_area
        r_outer = np.sqrt(outer_sector_area * (360/16) / np.pi)
        r_outer_diff = r_outer - r_inner
        r_adjusted_for_area.append(r_outer)
        r_outer_diffs.append(r_outer_diff)
    df_sector = pd.DataFrame({
        'direction': [direction]*len(frequencies),
        'strength': ['0-1']*len(frequencies),
        'frequency': frequencies,
        'r_outer_diff': r_outer_diffs
    })
    df_test_sectors = pd.concat([df_test_sectors, df_sector])
df_test_sectors = df_test_sectors.reset_index(drop=True)
df_test_sectors['direction'] = pd.Categorical(
    df_test_sectors['direction'], 
    df_test.direction.tolist() #sort the directions into the same order as those in df_test
)
df_test_sectors['frequency'] = df_test_sectors['frequency'].astype(float)
df_test_sectors = df_test_sectors.sort_values(['direction', 'frequency'])

fig = px.bar_polar(df_test_sectors, r='r_outer_diff', theta='direction', color='frequency', color_continuous_scale='YlGn')

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I am glad to have helped – this was a fun problem to solve!